# Elegant way to CONCAT up to certain length in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, concatenation

I am writing a view in MS SQL Server that is supposed to pull from up to, say, 5 email address fields and concatenate them into one EmailAddresses field.  That's the easy part.  The trick is that the resulting string can't be more than 100 characters long, and we don't want partial email addresses, so I can't just CONCAT and do a LEFT(EmailAddresses, 100).  The string has to end with the email address *before* the one that would put you over the 100 character limit.

The way I'm doing it right now is with a case when:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(Email1 + IsNull(';' + Email2, '') + IsNull(';' + Email3, '') + IsNull(';' + Email4, '')) <= 100
            THEN Email1 + IsNull(';' + Email2, '') + IsNull(';' + Email3, '') + IsNull(';' + Email4, '')
        WHEN LEN(Email1 + IsNull(';' + Email2, '') + IsNull(';' + Email3, '')) <= 100
            THEN Email1 + IsNull(';' + Email2, '') + IsNull(';' + Email3, '')
        WHEN LEN(Email + IsNull(';' + Email2, '')) <= 100
            THEN Email + IsNull(';' + Email2, '')
        ELSE Email1
    END as Email_Address
```

This actually works well, but it's ugly.  Is there a more elegant way to approach this situation?

Comment: what rdbms? sql server?

Comment: SQL Server, yes.  If it's invalid, they don't seem to mind - it runs just fine. :)  I got the format from MS documentation for the CASE WHEN THEN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These examples would work on SQL server 2012

```
declare @T table (id int identity(1,1), email1 varchar(80), email2 varchar(80), email3 varchar(80), email4 varchar(80));

insert into @T (email1,email2,email3,email4) values
('short1@test.com','short2@test.com','short3@test.com','short4@test.com'),
('john.doe@mail.com',null,'jane.doe@mail.com',null),
('longername1@longdomainname.com','longername2@longdomainname.com','longername3@longdomainname.com','longername4@longdomainname.com');


select id, 
concat(
 max(case when n=1 then m end),
 max(case when n=2 then ';'+m end),
 max(case when n=3 then ';'+m end),
 max(case when n=4 then ';'+m end)
 ) as emails
from 
(
select id, n, m, sum(len(m)+1) over (partition by id order by n ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as RunningTotal
from @T t0
cross apply (values (1,email1),(2,email2),(3,email3),(4,email4)) mails(n,m)
) q
where RunningTotal <= 100
group by id;
```

Or using the xml trick:

```
select id, 
STUFF((select ';'+m
 from 
 (
   select m, sum(len(m)+1) over (partition by id order by n ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as RunningTotal
   from @T t0
   cross apply (values (1,email1),(2,email2),(3,email3),(4,email4)) q(n,m)
   where t0.id = t.id
 ) q
 where RunningTotal <= 100
 FOR XML PATH ('')
),1,1,'') as mails
from @T t
group by id;
```

Or using case, concat, left, charindex and reverse (least 'ugly'?):

```
select id, 
(case 
 when len(emails)>100 
 then left(left(emails,101-charindex(';',reverse(left(emails,101)))),100)
 else emails 
 end) as emails
from (
    select id, concat(email1,';'+email2,';'+email3,';'+email4) as emails
    from @T
) q;
```

Or perhaps like this?

```
select id,
concat(email1,
       case when isnull(len(email1),0)+isnull(len(email2)+1,0) <= 100 then ';'+email2 end,
       case when isnull(len(email1),0)+isnull(len(email2)+1,0)+isnull(len(email3)+1,0) <= 100 then ';'+email3 end,
       case when isnull(len(email1),0)+isnull(len(email2)+1,0)+isnull(len(email3)+1,0)+isnull(len(email4)+1,0) <= 100 then ';'+email4 end
      ) as emails
from @T;
```

Comment: I've never gotten fancy with views, but I didn't realize you could have that much in them.  Interesting approach.

Comment: @JasonJacobs With views, I assume you mean more than 1 level of subquery? Anyway, I've added 2 more methods. Probably the 3th one is the least 'ugly'.

Answer (score 1):

What I'm about to suggest is terrible.  But, it's *an* alternative.

1. Concat all emails
2. Take the left-most 100 characters
3. `reverse` the string
4. `strpos` to find the first semi-colon (marking where you want to cut)
5. `rtrim` the length - strpos from (4)
6. `reverse` the string again

Comment: I'm assuming you're in Redshift.  Which if you are, you can also build a user-defined function via python.

Comment: That's an odd assumption.  Looks like SQL Server to me.